# How to break a recursive call before going into a void error

Tags: recursion, if-statement, scheme, racket

```
(define l '(* - + 4))

(define (operator? x)
    (or (equal? '+ x) (equal? '- x) (equal? '* x) (equal? '/ x)))

(define (tokes list)
  (if (null? list)(write "empty")
  (if (operator? (car list))

       ((write "operator")
        (tokes (cdr list)))

      (write "other"))))
```

The code works just fine til (tokes (cdr list))) reaches the end of file. Can someone give me a tip in how I can prevent that. I'm new at Scheme so I'm forgive me if the question is absurd.

Comment: Really does the code work until end of file?  In this line: `((write "operator")(tokes ...))` you're applying the result of `(write "operator")` to `(tokes ...)` - which should throw an error (and does when I try it)

Comment: That's what I meant. 
I suppose I didn't explain myself adequately. once cdr file takes in eof it gives me the proper void error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must make sure of advancing the recursion on each case (except the base case, when the list is `null`). In your code you're not making a recursive call for the `(write "other")` case. Also, you should use `cond` when there are several conditions to test, Let me explain with an example - instead of this:

```
(if condition1
    exp1
    (if condition2
        exp2
        (if condition3
            exp3
            exp4)))
```

Better write this, is much more readable and has the added benefit that you can write more than one expression after each condition *without* the need to use a `begin` form:

```
(cond (condition1 exp1) ; you can write additional expressions after exp1
      (condition2 exp2) ; you can write additional expressions after exp2
      (condition3 exp3) ; you can write additional expressions after exp3
      (else exp4))      ; you can write additional expressions after exp4
```

... Which leads me to the next point, be aware that you can write *only one* expression for each branch of an `if`, if more than one expression is needed for a given condition in an `if` form then you must surround them with a `begin`, for example:

```
(if condition
    ; if the condition is true
    (begin  ; if more than one expression is needed 
      exp1  ; surround them with a begin
      exp2) 
    ; if the condition is false
    (begin  ; if more than one expression is needed 
      exp3  ; surround them with a begin
      exp4))
```

Going back to your question - here's the general idea, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (tokes list)
  (cond ((null? list)
         (write "empty"))
        ((operator? (car list))
         (write "operator")
         <???>)   ; advance on the recursion
        (else
         (write "other")
         <???>))) ; advance on the recursion
```

Comment: Thank you Oscar, you've been a great help in all my questions!